# Vertically align text within input field of fixed-height without display: table or padding?

Tags: css, xhtml

The line-height property usually takes care of vertical alignment, but not with inputs. Is there a way to automatically center text without playing around with padding?

Comment: Without playing around with padding? Not in my experience. If you want it to render (nearly) the same across browsers, I have found that using padding is necessary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Opera 9.62, Mozilla 3.0.4, Safari 3.2 (for Windows) it helps, if you put some text or at least a whitespace within the same line as the input field.

```
<div style="line-height: 60px; height: 60px; border: 1px solid black;">
    <input type="text" value="foo" />&nbsp;
</div>
```

(imagine an &nbsp after the input-statement)

IE 7 ignores every CSS hack I tried.
I would recommend using padding for IE only. Should make it easier for you to position it correctly if it only has to work within one specific browser.

Comment: -1 This aligns the input field, not the text in the input field.

Comment: text-align: center; Applied this to CSS of textfield and it worked for me

Answer (score 104):

I ran into this problem myself.  I found that not specifying an input height, but using the font-height and padding combined, results in vertically aligned text.

For instance, lets say you want to have a 42px tall input box, with a font-size of 20px.  You could simply find the difference between the input height and the font-size, divide it by two, and set your padding to that amount.  In this case, you would have 22px total worth of padding, which is 11px on each side.

```
<input type="text" style="padding: 11px 0px 11px 0px; font-size: 20px;" />
```

That would give you a 42px tall input box with perfect vertical alignment.

Comment: Even though this works, the original question was how to solve this without padding.

Comment: As noted by Micros, this does work, but the original question was how to do it without padding, which does seem to be possible. I believe Chris Hawes answer is the simplest solution, and it doesn't require the use of padding.

Comment: Sometimes you need an explicit height, in which case doing it with padding is not acceptable.  While this does work, it doesn't address this situation (which is what the question asked). See Chris Hawes answer below for the correct answer without padding (i.e. "line-height").

Answer (score 63):

I've not tried this myself, but try setting:

```
height : 36px; //for other browsers
line-height: 36px; // for IE
```

Where 36px is the height of your input.

Comment: Actually the line-height property solved the problem in IE. I think this is the easiest way.

Comment: The only problem that I would see from this is if you have wrapping text.

Comment: I found line-height to also be needed, especially on iPhone 13 Safari

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm late to the party but hopefully this'll help anyone looking for a concise answer that does work across all major browsers (except IE6, we have decided to stop supporting that browser so I refuse to even look at it anymore).

```
    #search #searchbox {
    height: 21px;
    line-height: 21px;
}
```

cheers!
JP

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the answer on this page with the most votes is the best answer, but his math was wrong and I couldn't comment on it.

I needed a text input box to be exactly 40 pixels high including a 1 pixel border all the way around.  Of course I wanted the text vertically aligned in the center in all browsers.

1 pixel border top
1 pixel border bottom
8 pixel top padding
8 pixel bottom padding
22 pixel font size

1 + 1 + 8 + 8 + 22 = 40 pixels exactly.

One thing to remember is that you must remove your css height property or those pixels will get added to your total above.

```
<input type="text" style="padding-top:8px; padding-bottom:8px; margin: 0; border: solid 1px #000000; font-size:22px;" />
```

This is working in Firefox, Chrome, IE 8, and Safari.  I can only assume that if something simple like this is working in IE8, it should work similarly in 6, 7, and 9 but I have not tested it. Please let me know and I'll edit this post accordingly.

Comment: `I can only assume that if something simple like this is working in IE8, it should work similarly in 6, 7` - there are A LOT of very simple things (by today's standards at least) that work (even if half-assedly) in IE8, but are impossible in IE6, or even 7. As a reminder, IE6 didn't support as much as `position: fixed` or even transparent PNGs.

Answer (score 2):

Go for `line-height`.

The `vertical-align` tag works fine for the submit button but not for the text in the input field.
Setting `line-height` to the height of the input field works on all browsers. Incl IE7.

Comment: while this answer provides a good reason, it doesn't provide an answer. I'm trying it now and it doesn't even work. first, height overrides and renders line-height useless. second, line-height only makes the input box bigger/smaller and doesn't do anything to adjust the positioning of the text.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching and frustration a combo of setting height, line height and no padding worked for me when using a fixed height (24px) background image for a text input field.

```
.form-text {
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    background-image: url(input_text.png);
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 274px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: vertical-align will align the input element relative to the its parent, not the inside it.

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type=text]
{
   height: 15px; 
   line-height: 15px;
}
```

this is correct way to set vertical-middle position.

Comment: This exact solution was already given in multiple answers when you posted this.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't set the height of the input box, only set the font-size, that will be ok

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

```
<ul>
   <li>First group of text here.</li>
   <li><input type="" value="" /></li>
</ul>
```

then inside your CSS file,

```
ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

That should work for you.

Comment: You don't need 'display: block' when used with 'float'. Remember float = block.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
height: 21px;
line-height: 21px; /* FOR IE */
```

Because on some versions of IE (< 9) the property height is not properly interpreted.

Comment: This exact solution was already given in multiple answers when you posted this.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but the current answers won't work if you have box-sizing: border-box set (which a lot of people do for form elements these days).

Just reset the box sizing for IE8 to `box-sizing: content-box;` then use one of the padding / height answer.

Answer (score 0):

The inner vertical alignment will depend on font height and input height, so, it can be adjusted using padding !!!

Try some like :

```
.InVertAlign {
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   font-size: 2em;
   padding: 0px 14px 3px 5px;
}
```

...

```
<input type="text" class="InVertAlign" />
```

Remember to adjust the values on css class according to your needs !

Answer (score 0):

I was just working on this within MaterialUI's text inputs. Adding `padding-top: 0.5rem` to the input style worked for me. While this was adjusting the padding, at least you don't need to worry about adjusting for updates, much less different breakpoints.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't ideal but changing the bottom padding is the easiest solution. Anything else is too much overhead.

```
padding-bottom: 20%;
```

Answer (score -2):

You should remove your title text and use the input placeholder for your label's title. Some visual and CSS work after that and your form will be looking tight and user friendly. I'm aware of the disadvantages but this will completely relieve the alignment wrestling.

Answer (score -11):

If your element is a block element contained/or with display like so:

```
display: table-cel
```

Or, with an fixed line-height, you can  set the vertical align like so:

```
Vertical-Align: Middle;
```

It won't work for other cases, but it works fine on these conditions.

Comment: This only works in block elements with `display: table-cell`, or blocks with a fixed `line-height`.