# How to text align to center For IE browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have Search box as a shown in below image. I want to Align the text to center, right now the text inside the search box is slightly upper. Below is the CSS for it. This situation only happens in IE browser. Fire Fox is fine.

```
.search_results_input {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    font: 12px/24px AntennaRegular,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    height: 30px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Including the html of the search box / text in front would help.

Comment: The following link is probably what you want.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326650/vertically-align-text-within-input-field-of-fixed-height-without-display-table

Comment: works fine for me in IE http://jsfiddle.net/SWBwt/

Comment: @m4tt1mus I tried line-height and worked fine in IE7/IE8/IE9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the line-height of the input to the height of the box and I think that should fix it.