# How to vertically align text in input type="text"?

Tags: html, css

There is `<input type="text" />` I need to set vertical alignment of the entered text. For example middle or top.
http://jsfiddle.net/eSPMr/

Comment: Answered here -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/945812/572939

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use padding to fake it since vertical-align doesn't work on text inputs.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eSPMr/388/)**

**CSS**

```
.date-input {     
    width: 145px;
    padding-top: 80px;
}​
```

Comment: It does not work

Comment: In my case it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 13):

An alternative is to use `line-height`:
http://jsfiddle.net/DjT37/

```
.bigbox{
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

This tends to be more consistent when you want a specific height as you don't need to calculate padding based on font-size and desired height, etc.

Comment: In Chrome, changing the `line-height` in the Fiddle doesn't seem to have any effect. What am I missing?

Comment: The vertical alignment will depend on font height and input height, so, it can be adjusted using padding !!!

Comment: No it can't. No matter what you do text is aligned in the middle vertically. So there is not way to align it at the top?

Answer (score 11):

```
input[type=text]
{
   height: 15px; 
   line-height: 15px;
}
```

this is correct way to set vertical-middle position.

Comment: Does not work as shown.

Comment: Doesn't work in textarea.

Answer (score 10):

The `<textarea>` element automatically aligns text at the top of a textbox, if you don't want to use CSS to force it.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a div tag seems to be the only way to FORCE that:

```
<div style="vertical-align: middle"><div><input ... /></div></div>
```

May be other tags like span works as like div do.

Comment: Does not work as shown

Answer (score 2):

I found this question while looking for a solution to my own problem. The previous answers rely on padding to make the text appear at the top or bottom of the input or use a combination of height and line-height to align the text to the vertical middle.

Here is an alternative solution to making the text appear in the middle using a div and positioning. Check out the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xk4m2mqg/).

```
<style type="text/css">
    div {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 300px;
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
    }

    input {
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center; /* Optional */
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <input type="text" value="Hello world!" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

IF vertical align won't work use padding.
`padding-top: 10px;`
it will shift the text to the bottom or 
        `padding-bottom: 10px;`
to shift the text in the text box to top

adjust the padding size till it suit the size you want.
Thats the hack