# Text input - text appears at the middle?

Tags: css, html, text, input

So it's very simple but I can't find the answer. The text on my text field appears at the middle and I want it to appear at the top left corner like it normally does.

This is the CSS

```
.DivMessage {
        position: inherit;
        top: 460px;
        left: 290px;
        font-family: times, serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
        background-color: #cce4ff;
        width: 645px;
        height: 115px;
    }
```

And the Html is just

```
<input class="DivMessage" type="text">
```

Comment: 115px? That's a very tall single-line-of-text input...

Comment: Why is your input field so large? Wouldn't a `textarea` field be a better fit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355557/how-to-vertically-align-text-in-input-type-text ?

Comment: "Middle" horizontally, or "Middle" vertically?  I suspect your text is probably left-justified horizontally ... and I suspect your text field height is so high it's centered *vertically*.  If you want to control vertical alignment ... your best bet is probably to use something *OTHER* than a "text" field.  "textarea" perhaps? Or a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if you should be using a `textarea` here instead of an input, but, if for whatever reason I'm wrong and you need to use an `input`, you will want to lose the height and add some padding in order to align the text to the top:

```
.DivMessage {
    position: inherit;
    top: 460px;
    left: 290px;
    font-family: times, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #cce4ff;
    width: 645px;
    padding: 0 0 115px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/phJNn/

Notice how I removed the `height` and replaced it with 115px of padding on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

all you need is to do the text-align to any side, right, left or center. thank you.

```
.input {text-align:left;}
```