# center text inside html5 date input

Tags: html, css

I cant for the life of me figure out how to center text inside of a html5 date input. As you can see I can change the color of the text but cant center it. i have tried multiple things in css as well

```css
input.element.text{text-align:center;/* dont work here */color:green;line-height: 30px;}/* change color but not align*/

input[type=date]{
line-height: 46px;
height: 30px;
width:300px;
text-align: center;/* dont work here */
text-align-last: center;
 color:red;/* used to test */
}

input[type=text]{ color:blue;/* used to test */
text-align: center;/* dont work here */
text-align-last: center;
 
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="dob" class="element" size="" maxlength="15" value="" type="text" placeholder="" required>
```

Comment: Your text is already centralised (if you account for the scrollbar and dropdown). Are you looking to move it slightly further to the right so it's centralised even when those are hidden?

Comment: just want the text centered when the user sees it every otehr input is centered
https://image.ibb.co/koOttU/Untitled.png

Comment: I have double-checked this on a text element without modifying the `display` type of the box - it got centered as it should.

Comment: I see a class assignment in the markup of the input field. Have you attached a `text-align` to the class definition within your CSS?

Answer (score 0):

```
.bigbox{
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

Source: [How to vertically align text in input type=“text”? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12355875/2825284)

Answer (score -1):

Input is an inline element you can either change it's display to a block and then call text-align or as I've done wrap it in a div and call text-align on the div to place the content inside.

Divs have block display by default.

```css
div{
text-align:center;
}
input.element.text{text-align:center;/* dont work here */color:green;line-height: 30px;}/* change color but not align*/

input[type=date]{
line-height: 46px;
height: 30px;
width:300px;
text-align: center;/* dont work here */
text-align-last: center;
 color:red;/* used to test */
}

input[type=text]{ color:blue;/* used to test */
text-align: center;/* dont work here */
text-align-last: center;
 
}
```

```html
<div><input type="date" name="dob" class="element" size="" maxlength="15" value="" type="text" placeholder="" required></div>
```

Comment: That centers the input box on the page, but the text inside of the input field isn't adjusted.