# How to align Input element text in middle in mac

Tags: css, css-selectors, font-face, webfonts

I developed a website using Slate Pro Regular and Slate Pro Bold fonts. It's working fine in windows but in Mac, input element text pushed up.  Please find screenshots for reference
[Input element in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB0Vs.png) and
[Alignment issue in Mac chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjN1r.png)

I tried below
[How to vertically align text in input type="text"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355557/how-to-vertically-align-text-in-input-type-text) and
https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/vertical-align-on-text-input/

Please, anyone help me to fix the Input element alignment issues in Mac.

```css
.container {
    max-width: 1040px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.form-input {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'SlatePro Bold';
    color: #565656;
}

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

.enroll-form-input.form-input input:not([type='radio']) {
    border: 1px solid #2b5795;
    font-family: 'SlatePro Regular';
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="enroll-doctor">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row form-center">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-input enroll-form-input">
                            <label for="licensefname">License first name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="License_First_Name__c" id="licensefname" placeholder="*John" value="" maxlength="100" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-required-message="*License first name required" data-parsley-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]+(([',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/g" data-parsley-pattern-message="*Invalid License first name">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-input enroll-form-input">
                            <label for="licenselname">License last name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="License_Last_Name__c" id="licenselname" placeholder="*Smith" value="" maxlength="100" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-required-message="*License last name required" data-parsley-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]+(([',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/g" data-parsley-pattern-message="*Valid license last name required">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: I'm on a Mac and see it centered correctly in the demo. Are you sure there are no other styles impacting this on your site?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro alignment issue is there in Mac right?

Comment: The issue should be visible in the question itself. Users should not have to browse somewhere else. Also, don't share credentials in a public place!

Comment: @Anitha I checked this on Mac. I'm not 100% sure but the problem seems to happen due to how this font is rendered on Mac.

Comment: @OzgurSar I tried to check in browser stack, even I found that issue with Font. I tried height: 40px, line-height: 40px for input element but not worked.

Comment: Please, anyone, help me to fix alignment issue in Mac.