# Positioning of text inside input

Tags: css, input

I have an input with `height: 250px` as you can see in it's text is in center. Is there any way to place align it to top left corner?

```css
#messageBox
{
    width: 200px;
 height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<input id="messageBox">
```

Comment: This is one gigantic input hehe. Use textarea for this ^^

Comment: Use textarea instead of simple input... !!!

Comment: Lol where is the `type` attr of you input? this is not a valid markup

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326650/vertically-align-text-within-input-field-of-fixed-height-without-display-table/945812#945812

Comment: @Tambo: yes, it's valid; if `type` is not supplied, or not recognised by the browser, then it defaults to `type"=text"`. See: [`<input />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

Answer (score 11):

Use a `<textarea>` instead:

```css
#messageBox{
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="messageBox"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 6):

Or if you need input and you don't need more rows, you can use padding instead height.

For example this code, but it's look crazy:

```css
#messageBox {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 0 250px 0;
}
```

```html
<input id="messageBox" value="test">
```

Comment: +1, this answer does the job and does not change the premise of the question :)

Answer (score 4):

Add bottom padding with `box-sizing` (so that the padding doesn't increase the height of the input):

```css
#messageBox
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  padding-bottom: 222px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<input id="messageBox" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add padding and let the height auto compute.

I assume that you know about `textarea`.

However, if you want the single line `input` field to have a tall box for design
purposes, it can be done.

**Design Note:** This styling allows you to place a background image below the text input area without having to add extra mark-up, which may be useful at times.

```css
#messageBox
{
  width: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 250px; /* approximately... */
  background:  0 30px no-repeat url(http://placekitten.com/1000/500);
}
```

```html
<input id="messageBox" value="Test">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the HTML as,

```
<textarea id="messageBox"></textarea>
```

Use textarea instead of invalid input

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<textarea id="messageBox"></textarea>
```

css

```
#messageBox
{
width: 200px;
height: 250px;
resize:none
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/16sb2rnb/3/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the textarea element instead.

```
<textarea id="messageBox"></textarea>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/16sb2rnb/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<textarea>` element to achieve this.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the op and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension (here: why is textarea a good alternavie way? Maybe with a smal exaple).

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, change `<input>` to `<textarea>`

```css
#messageBox {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="messageBox" rows="6" cols="50">
```

To increase height, just add more to `rows`