# How to vertically top-align the text in a INPUT text element?

Tags: html, css

I have a tall INPUT (type=text) element which is sized at 100%. The containing element has a specific height (which is dynamic).

What I want is to be able to put the text at the top of the INPUT element. I've seen a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326650/vertically-align-text-within-input-field-of-fixed-height-without-display-table/945812#945812%20few) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355557/how-to-vertically-align-text-in-input-type-text%20answers) use padding to vertically centre it, but I could not get that to place the text at the top of the element. I'm not able to set the height of the element.

Example HTML (or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yf5f82vx/)):

```
<body>
<div class="outer">
<input type="text" value ="textcontent"></input>
</div>
</body>
```

and CSS:

```
body { background-color:gray;}

.outer {
    height:480px;
    background-color:pink;
    margin-top:100px;
}

input {
    height:100%;
    background-color:lightgray;
    padding-top:0px;
    line-height:100px;
}
```

Can this be done without setting the height of the element? Browsers I need to support: Chrome, FF, IE9 & IE11.

Thanks
Dave

Comment: Why input and not textarea?

Comment: Any specific reason to use `input` and not `textarea`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically align text within input field of fixed-height without display: table or padding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326650/vertically-align-text-within-input-field-of-fixed-height-without-display-table)

Comment: As the others have said, if you are wanting a multiline text input then I would use a textarea, it has the additional bonus that the text will wrap when it hits the end of the line

Comment: Since you want the input to happen at the top of the area couldn't you simply put the input field in a div and give the div the right height and lightgreen background?

Comment: I can't use a TEXTAREA as the content is limited to one line. But the requirement is to display the content in a large box (this is how it looked in Silverlight and we've to make it look the same).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have only input element and achieve this, then set **padding-bottom** and not height.

Once you set height, by default the text will be shown in the middle of the element.

```
input {
  padding-bottom: 462px;
  background-color:lightgreen;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yf5f82vx/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the textarea insted of the text input.

That way the text will start from the top and will wrap the text if its have more charactors that the width.

check the below ex

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pun0r0k6/2/)

```
'<body>
 <div class="outer">
 <textarea >textcontent</textarea>
 </div>
 </body>'

'body { background-color:gray;}

.outer {
height:480px;
background-color:pink;
margin-top:100px;
overflow:hidden;
}

textarea {
background-color: lightgray;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 100%;
line-height: 50px;
max-height: 100%;
padding-top: 0;
resize: none;
}'
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't use a TEXTAREA as the content is limited to one line.

Comment: use white-space to fix that white-space: nowrap;