# What CSS properties influence the "height" property value?

Tags: html, css, height, font-size

### Code

```css
input {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="test" />
```

### Problem

I am trying to understand what causes my *input* to get its `height` changed (I get it increased).

What else would influence the `height` value for the input?

My problem is that I need to **not** set the `height` on the element but have it just dependant on other properties.

If I had `box-sizing: border-box` I would also have to specify `padding` and `border`. But with *content-box* it seems I am missing to set some property to indirectly influence the *input* element `height`.

### Screenshot (from Chrome)

As you see the calculated `height` is not influenced from the `line-height`.
On Firefox instead it seems to behave correctly.

[image]

Comment: line-height will set automatically the height to 20px

Comment: May I ask why you have to not set `height`?

Comment: @CodeiSir Damn curiosity ;) Actually I need to be free/flexible, and the ```height``` must be dependant on secondary properties values. I don't know (and don't want to know) the exact value of the final height of the element.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan added a screenshot. As you see the ```line-height``` is not sufficient.

Comment: It's a good question. Note that input was typically originally implemented as a replaced element - outside of the influence of CSS - so now it may retain some remnants of that sizing behaviour to be backward compatible. So the height may not be computed consistently cross-browser.

Comment: Mmmh I am not sure what replacing-element implementation you are talking about. Would be interesting to read (and brainstorm) about it, if you could refer to some article or page regarding that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/327509/4339170

Comment: Replaced elements are described here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/conform.html#replaced-element. But it causes a lot of confusion. Basically a replaced element is one where the rendering is delegated from the browser to the operating system. It's up to the browser to choose which elements it does this for, and modern browsers don't really do it at all. But they sometimes have render things similar to how they would have been rendered if they had been delegated to the O/S so that old web pages don't break too badly.

Comment: @Alohci thanks for the explanation. 
By the way the issue also happens (this time on Firefox) with a normal **div** (that I set to ```display: inline-block```). So it doesn't seem to be related to *replaced-elements* (although I've learned something new with it!) but to all elements (or at least the *inline* ones).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only solution I could find is to specify an explicit `height` and force the browser to the desired value.

```css
input {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```