# How to align text in input on top of div

Tags: html, css, z-index

When putting a div behind another div the text in bot div elements is aligned.

```css
.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.box {
  height: 34px;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: #555555;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) none;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.top {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.underlayer {
  top: -48px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
      color: #c8c8c8;
      margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div type="text" class="box top">20-123</div>
  <div class="box underlayer">20-123-20</div>
</div>
```

When the div with class `top` is replaced with an input, the text is 1px off, though the border is still aligned correctly.

```css
.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.box {
  height: 34px;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #555555;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) none;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.top {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.underlayer {
  top: -48px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
      color: #c8c8c8;
      margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" value="20-123" class="box top">
  <div class="box underlayer">20-123-20</div>
</div>
```

I can't put my head around it. Somebody here to explain it and suggest how to resolve this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertically align text within input field of fixed-height without display: table or padding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326650/vertically-align-text-within-input-field-of-fixed-height-without-display-table)

Comment: Did you see that you also a different font-family ?

Comment: Did not notice the difference in font-family. Changed it in the examples, does not help though.

Comment: The height and line-height can not be set to the same value as suggested in the referenced article. Also i still cannot explain why the text is not aligned.

Comment: Based on the answer you validated, it is actualy due to line-height as in the subject I post in duplicate. But now you have just the explication that fit you better than the original subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of how inputs are handled. The textfield inside an input-element is streched to fit the box size. In this case 34px. So the fix is to increase the div's line-height to match the 34px of the input.

```css
.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.box {
  height: 34px;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-family: Verdana!important;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #555555;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) none;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.top {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.underlayer {
  top: -48px;
  line-height: 34px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
      color: #c8c8c8;
      margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" value="20-123" class="box top">
  <div class="box underlayer">20-123-20</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You change `underlayer` from `div` to `input`. It changes second div's font to the one used by inputs. Because `underlayer` has lower z-index, it will never be selected by user, no it doesn't create any danger. You also set second input's display to `block`.

Unfortunately, I don't know why it originally happened, so I can't explain it.

```css
.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.box {
  height: 34px;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #555555;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) none;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.top {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.underlayer {
  top: -48px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
      color: #c8c8c8;
      margin:0;
   display: block;
   tabindex: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" value="20-123" class="box top">
  <input class="box underlayer" value="20-123-20">
</div>
```

Comment: Although it is a creative solution, the ```underlayer``` input element can be accessed by keyboard navigation. Setting attribute ```tabindex``` to value ```-1``` prevents this.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your fonts.
You have one font for the underlayer and one for the other.

I also add a font-size and hide your second box so you can move the top position of your underlayer to match with the text on top.

It's probably not the best way to do it, but it works.

```css
.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.box {
  height: 34px;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #555555;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) none;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.top {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.underlayer {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px; 
  top: -44px;
  left: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 0px solid #cccccc;
  position: relative;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
      color: #c8c8c8;
      margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" value="20-123" class="box top">
  <div class="box underlayer">20-123-20</div>
</div>
```